# How can I toggle databases in Django?

Tags: django

Django's `settings.py` file has a `DATABASES` dictionary that stores configuration information for any number of database backends:

```py
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testing',
        'USER': 'bert',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'remotemysql.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'dev': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'development',
        'USER': 'ernie',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'remotemysql.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    ...
}
```

I would expect the Django authors to have included a method to easily switch among these configuration options, such as a separate variable somewhere

```
USE_THIS_DB = 'test';
```

in order to easily switch between testing, development, production, etc. databases.

I can't find this option.  The only information I can find about switching databases is to manually rename the different configuration options in `DATABASES` so that the one I want to use is called `default`, which seems unnecessarily clunky, error-prone, and non-portable.

Is there no way to more elegantly switch Django among different databases at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just DIY in Python ?

```py
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testing',
        'USER': 'bert',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'remotemysql.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'dev': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'development',
        'USER': 'ernie',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'remotemysql.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
}

USE_THIS_DB = 'test'

DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES[USE_THIS_DB]
```

Comment: Huh.  Would not have thought of that.  I'll give it a shot